How to update data in component that is not part of page in next.js?
Im learning next.js so Im creating simple app for project management with help of firebase. I do understand that when Im adding something into database I can then use revalidatePath to get new updated data list from the database. But how can I handle use case when the data are not displayed on a page but rather in some type of component that is part of layout.tsx.
My case:
I have a sidebar with all the projects for currently logged user. This sidebar is part of layout.tsx so it's not directly part of any page. Then I have a page with form that actually creates project. When I create this project, how can I update the project list inside the sidebar?
This is my server action that handles project creation:
"use server";

import { Project } from "@/app/models/Project";
import { db } from "@/config/firebase";
import { addDoc, collection, getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";

export const CreateProject = async (formData: { name: string; color: string }, user: string) => {
  try {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, "projects");

    const projectRef = await addDoc(collectionRef, {
      name: formData.name,
      color: formData.color,
      user,
    });

    const project = {
      id: projectRef.id,
      name: formData.name,
      color: formData.color,
      user,
    };

    return project;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error adding document: ", error);
  }
};

And this is my server action to get projects:
export const GetProjects = async (user: string) => {
  try {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, "projects");

    const q = query(collectionRef, where("user", "==", user));

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    const projects: Project[] = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      name: doc.data().name,
      color: doc.data().color,
      user: doc.data().user,
    }));

    return projects;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  }
}


ideally layout.tsx should act as complete wrapper to your web application for standards. you can create a skeleton in layout.tsx to wrap sidebar inside layout.tsx.
Not sure if you are using redux and sidebar is wrapped under redux., if yes., you can access it.
